# How is semicolon derivative notation defined for multiple derivatives?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, notation, differentiation

I have a covector $\eta_\mu$. Then I have some notation which says $$\eta_{\alpha;\beta\gamma}$$ What does this mean? I understand that given a vector $A^\alpha$, that $$A^\alpha_{;\beta}=\nabla_\beta A^\alpha=(\nabla A)^\alpha_\beta$$This makes sense to me. However I do not understand what happens when two indices follow the semi-colon. If I had to guess, I would go with $$\eta_{\alpha;\beta\gamma}=\nabla_\beta\nabla_\gamma\eta_\alpha$$But I am not sure of this.

Comment: @JohnDoe your guess is almost correct. Actually, $\eta_{\alpha;\beta \gamma} = \eta_{\alpha;\beta;\gamma} = \nabla_{\gamma} \nabla_{\beta} \eta_{\alpha}$. Your result is only the same in the flat spacetime, where the Riemann tensor (which is related to the commutator of covariant derivatives) vanishes.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus So you're saying that I can think of it like this: after a semi-colon is introduced in one of the indices, everything that follows also has an invisible semi-colon in front of it. Is this correct?

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus That should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty this question was put on hold earlier, which is when that comment was made (But yes, I do agree with you)

Comment: @JohnDoe yes, that is correct.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty At this point I'd suggest just posting the answer yourself. (Or really, I'd say it's fair game for anyone who comes along and wants some free reputation. I'm kind of tired otherwise I might do it myself :-p )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, $$\eta_{\alpha;\beta \gamma} = \eta_{\alpha;\beta;\gamma} = \nabla_{\gamma} \nabla_{\beta} \eta_{\alpha}$$ Your result is only the same in the flat spacetime, where the Riemann tensor (which is related to the commutator of covariant derivatives) vanishes.